# Add sections of a table column as new Columns - Power Query

Tags: excel, group-by, split, pivot, powerquery

I am having the following `Unpivoted table` that contains `Stat-tested % values` and their `Stat-letters` and `Stat-Letters position indicators` on separate rows.

```
----------------------------------------
CODE  |  ATTR      |  TEXT     |  VALUE
----------------------------------------
1       mean        I love it     0.45
2       mean        I love it     0.67
3       mean        I love it     0.49
4       mean        I love it     0.21
5       mean        I love it     0.66
1       mean        I love it     abd
2       mean        I love it     e
3       mean        I love it     cd
4       mean        I love it     a
5       mean        I love it     ab
1       mean        I love it     1
2       mean        I love it     1
3       mean        I love it     1
4       mean        I love it     1
5       mean        I love it     1
1       wt-mean     I hate it     0.22
2       wt-mean     I hate it     0.56
3       wt-mean     I hate it     0.13
4       wt-mean     I hate it     0.89
5       wt-mean     I hate it     0.50
1       wt-mean     I hate it     ab
2       wt-mean     I hate it     ae
3       wt-mean     I hate it     c
4       wt-mean     I hate it     b
5       wt-mean     I hate it     de
1       wt-mean     I hate it     1
2       wt-mean     I hate it     1
3       wt-mean     I hate it     1
4       wt-mean     I hate it     1
5       wt-mean     I hate it     1
```

I want to group on the CODE column and add the `Stat-tested Letters` and `position indicators` as separate columns like below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
CODE  |  ATTR      |  TEXT     |  VALUE     LETTERS     POSITION
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       mean        I love it     0.45      abd         1
2       mean        I love it     0.67      e           1
3       mean        I love it     0.49      cd          1
4       mean        I love it     0.21      a           1
5       mean        I love it     0.66      ab          1
1       wt-mean     I hate it     0.22      ab          1
2       wt-mean     I hate it     0.56      ae          1
3       wt-mean     I hate it     0.13      c           1
4       wt-mean     I hate it     0.89      b           1
5       wt-mean     I hate it     0.50      de          1
```

The problem i am encountering while grouping the data on Value column, is that the column has mixed data types (text, number). How to split these into individual columns as shown below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert new custom-columns for this, check with `try` if the value is a number.

My Source is `Tabelle1`

```
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    Change_Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"CODE", Int64.Type}, {"ATTR", type text}, {"TEXT", type text}, {"VALUE", type any}}),
    Custom_Number = Table.AddColumn(Change_Type, "Number", each if try Number.From([VALUE]) < 1 otherwise null = true then [VALUE] else null),
    Custom_Letters = Table.AddColumn(Custom_Number, "Letters", each if (try Number.From([VALUE]) >= 1 otherwise null) = null then [VALUE] else null),
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte" = Table.AddColumn(Custom_Letters, "POSITION", each if [Number] = null and [Letters]= null then [VALUE] else null),
    Grouped_Rows = Table.Group(#"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte", {"CODE", "ATTR", "TEXT"}, {{"VALUE", each List.Max([Number]), type nullable number}, {"LETTERS", each List.Max([Letters]), type nullable text}, {"POSITION", each List.Max([POSITION]), type nullable number}})
in
    Grouped_Rows
```

[image]

Comment: You could shorten your if conditions a little bit like `if try Number.From([VALUE]) < 1 otherwise false then [VALUE] else null` and `if try Number.From([VALUE]) > 1 otherwise true then [VALUE] else null` and for the third column one could use `if try Number.From([VALUE]) >= 1 otherwise false then [VALUE] else null`. But nice solution.